# How do I specify a default folder for bash terminal in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, git-bash

I've changed visual studio code settings so that by default it's opening git bash instead of default one.
Now for a specific project I'd like to make it always open in a specific subfolder by default so that I don't have to execute `cd MyFolder` manually every time before I move on to next commands I need for my work.
How do I do that?

Didn't find anything valuable or working at google, msdn or chat gpt.